# How do I change one button to toggle current/future events when clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page I created showing three pictures of runners.
Under each picture is a list of three events. When the user clicks on an event, they will see the info(date/location/city) listed under the event.
When they click a button, then everything should change to future events. Along with new info under the new list of future events. Here is my HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var v = false;

    $("button#futureEvents").click(function(){
        if (v == false){
            
            $("li.sprint").text("Snowball Sprint");
            $(".sprint").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>1/14/18<br/>Mosquito Hill<br/>New London</li>");
            
            $("li.iron").text("Winter Warrior");
            $(".iron").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>2/06/18<br/>Bay Beach<br/>Green Bay</li>");
            
            $("li.twilight").text("Big Chill Run");
            $(".twilight").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>2/24/18<br/>Mid Valley Golf Course<br/>De Pere</li>");
            
            $("li.fox").text("Frosty Indoor Marathon");
            $(".fox").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>1/15/18<br/>TryIt Ice Arena<br/>Neenah</li>");
            
            $("li.new").text("Valentine Run");
            $(".new").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>2/12/18 <br/>Green Isle Park<br/> De Pere</li>");
            
            $("li.winnebago").text("Snowball Marathon");
            $(".winnebago").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>3/03/18 <br/>Menominee Park <br/>Oshkosh</li>");
            
            $("li.cheese").text("Trailbreaker Marathon");
            $(".cheese").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>4/02/18 <br/>Leach Amphitheatre<br/> Oshkosh</li>");
            
            $("li.chain").text("Jailbreak Marathon");
            $(".chain").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>4/16/18 <br/>Menominee Park <br/>Oshkosh</li>");
            
            $("li.foxCities").text("Cellcom Marathon");
            $(".foxCities").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>5/20/18<br/> Lombardi Atrium<br/> Green Bay</li>");
            
            $("button").replaceWith("<button id='currentEvents'>Current Events</button>");
                
            v = true;
        }//end v==false if statement
    });//end fututre events button


    $("button#currentEvents").click(function(){
        if (v == true){
            
            $("li.sprint").text("Mini Sprint");
            $(".sprint").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>");
            
            $("li.iron").text("Iron Horse");
            $(".iron").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>11/06/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>");
            
            $("li.twilight").text("Twilight Trail");
            $(".twilight").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>11/13/17<br/>River's Edge Park<br/>Wrightstown</li>");
            
            $("li.fox").text("Fox River Marathon");
            $(".fox").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>10/15/17<br/>Pierce Park<br/>Appleton</li>");
            
            $("li.new").text("N.E.W. Half Marathon");
            $(".new").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>10/29/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>");
            
            $("li.winnebago").text("Winnebago Run");
            $(".winnebago").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>11/27/17<br/>Menominee Park<br/>Oshkosh</li>");
            
            $("li.cheese").text("Cheesehead Marathon");
            $(".cheese").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>9/24/17<br/>Pamperin Park<br/>Green Bay</li>");
            
            $("li.chain").text("Chain O'Lakes Marathon");
            $(".chain").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>Marathon 10/29/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>");
            
            $("li.foxCities").text("Fox Cities Marathon");
            $(".foxCities").next().children().replaceWith("<li class='info'>11/12/17<br/>Menominee Park<br/>Oshkosh</li>");
            
            $("button").replaceWith("<button id='futureEvents'>Future Events</button>");
            
            v = false;
        }//end v==true if statement 
    });//end current events button


    $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).next().children().toggle();
    });//end click function

});//end document ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="race_box">
  <img src="images/run1.jpg" /><br />
  <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>

  <div class="races" id="5k">
    <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="sprint">Mini Sprint</li>
      <ul>
        <li class="info">10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>
      </ul>
      <li class="iron">Iron Horse</li>
      <ul>
        <li class="info">11/06/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
      </ul>
      <li class="twilight">Twilight Trail</li>
      <ul>
        <li class="info">11/13/17<br/>River's Edge Park<br/>Wrightstown</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--  End of '5k' div-->
</div>
<!-- End of 'run1' div-->
<nav>
  <button id="futureEvents">Future Events</button>
</nav>
```

UPDATE: Everything is almost working now. However, when I click the future events button, it shows the future events(as it should), the button is changed to current events(as it should) but it will not do anything! I can click it to see the future events, but cannot click it again to see the current events. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing at all is working, probably you have forgotten to include jQuery in your page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Adding this line in the html would solve it.

Since i have added it in the snippet when i edited your question and the values are changing, i am writing this answer.

You need jQuery file because, `$.` is a jQuery function which is similar to typing `jquery.`

---

Another issue i found was that you are replacing the class of the elements. after you click the button, you dont find the sprint class at all!

you could use `$(".sprint").html("<li class='snowball'>Snowball Sprint</li>");` instead of `$(".sprint").replaceWith("<li class='snowball'>Snowball Sprint</li>")`

or if you you want the class to be snowball, then you could not acess the children of sprint class because that does not exist!

Also add a class to the ul Element like:

```
<ul class="SprintList">
    <li class="info">10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>
</ul>
```

Since **ul cannot be a child of an li element**, you would make another class for this element which is supposed to be under sprint element.

and use the jquery like:
`$(".sprintList .info").html("1/14/18<br/>Mosquito Hill<br/>New London");`
to change the date and place.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var v = false;

  $("button#futureEvents").click(function() {
    if (v == false) {

      /*if (.info==show){
          $(".info").hide();
          };//end info if statement*/

      $(".sprint").html("<li class='snowball'>Snowball Sprint</li>");
      $(".sprintList .info").html("1/14/18<br/>Mosquito Hill<br/>New London");

      $(".iron").html("<li class='winter'>Winter Warrior</li>");
      $(".ironList .info").html("2/06/18<br/>Bay Beach<br/>Green Bay");

      $(".twilight").html("<li class='bigChill'>Big Chill Run</li>");
      $(".twilightList .info").html("2/24/18<br/>Mid Valley Golf Course<br/>De Pere");

      $("button").replaceWith("<button id='currentEvents'>Current Events</button>");

      v = true;
    } //end v==false if statement
  }); //end fututre events button

  $("button#currentEvents").click(function() {



  }); //end current events button

  $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).next().children().toggle();
  }); //end click function

}); //end document ready
```

```html
<!--I add the JQuery here-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="race_box">
  <img src="images/run1.jpg" /><br />
  <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>

  <div class="races" id="5k">
    <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="sprint">Mini Sprint</li>
      <ul class="sprintList">
        <li class="info">10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>
      </ul>
      <li class="iron">Iron Horse</li>
      <ul class="ironList">
        <li class="info">11/06/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
      </ul>
      <li class="twilight">Twilight Trail</li>
      <ul class="twilightList">
        <li class="info">11/13/17<br/>River's Edge Park<br/>Wrightstown</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--  End of '5k' div-->
</div>
<!-- End of 'run1' div-->
<nav>
  <button id="futureEvents">Future Events</button>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No I have jQuery in the HTML. I just posted a portion of the HTML, not all of it. I can get the button to change, and I can get the list names to change to the correct future names. However, I cannot get the future .info for the future events to show up at all

Comment: oh! the children! i dint notice... let me check!!

Comment: Almost Prashanth! You got as far as I did. But in both of our code, if you click the future button, everything works great. It changes to current events. But if you click current events, nothing happens. That's the part I can't figure out

Comment: The `onclick` function works only on the elements that are initialized during the first page load only. You could use the `on('click', function(){})` instead for the replaced button.

Comment: ok, but even if I keep the button the same, keep the id the same, and only change the text with the .text method, it still will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace, use the .addClass() and .removeClass() methods in jQuery.

For example:

```js
$('h1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('blue');
})
```

```css
h1 {
    color: red;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Click Me</h1>
```

Comment: Doesn't the addclass and removeclass just add and remove css classes to an element? The replace with will replace the li event, it's just changing the info that was attached to the original event that has me flustered. I can get the event name to change, but then I cannot get the new info to display when the new event list is clicked. How do I add a ul and then a li to a li I just replaced?

Comment: Are you dynamically adding new events or just showing and hiding preloaded data?

Answer (score 0):

Should the ul with the info not be part of the first li?

For example:

```
  <li class="sprint">Mini Sprint
  <ul>
    <li class="info">10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
```